# Twig invalid render array keys from a valid array

Tags: theming, 8

In hook_preprocess_menu I am creating an array to send to the menu twig tpl (eventually it will be entity paragraph data but for now they are hard values as examples). However, I just receive array key invalid errors. How should this be formatted correctly for the template?

```
function hook_preprocess_menu__main_menu(&$vars) {

  $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
  if($node->field_menu_highlights){
    $highlight_values = $node->get('field_menu_highlights')->getValue();

    foreach ($highlight_values as $key => $item){
      $ent = \Drupal\paragraphs\Entity\Paragraph::load($item['target_id']);
      $vars['highlight'][$key]['title'] = 'Title here';
      $vars['highlight'][$key]['desc'] = 'Description here';

    }
  }
}
```

The template:

```
{% for value in highlight %}
    {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Error eg:

```
User error: "title" is an invalid render array key in Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children() (line 97 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element.php).
```

Comment: try value.title

Comment: thanks, but the error still persists

Answer (score 1):

Build the array with renderable children:

```
  $vars['highlight'][$key] = [
    'title' => [
      '#markup' => 'Title here',
    ],
    'desc' => [
      '#markup' => 'Description here',
    ],
  ];
```

Now the loop to render each value separately should work or have the same result by rendering the complete render array:

```
{{ highlight }}
```